# How to print the value of struct members in c (with a pointer to a struct)

Tags: c, pointers, struct

I'm trying to debug a program. There is a function being called `prv_write()`

```
static uint8_t prv_write(uint16_t instanceId,
                     int numData,
                     lwm2m_data_t * dataArray,
                     lwm2m_object_t * objectP)
```

This function is being passed (3rd argument) a pointer to a struct `lwm2m_data_t` which is defined as:

```
typedef struct _lwm2m_data_t lwm2m_data_t;

struct _lwm2m_data_t
{
    lwm2m_data_type_t type;
    uint16_t    id;
    union
    {
        bool        asBoolean;
        int64_t     asInteger;
        double      asFloat;
        struct
        {
            size_t    length;
            uint8_t * buffer;
        } asBuffer;
        struct
        {
            size_t         count;
            lwm2m_data_t * array;
        } asChildren;
        struct
        {
            uint16_t objectId;
            uint16_t objectInstanceId;
        } asObjLink;
     } value;
};
```

Could somebody explain how I could print the values of `length` and `buffer` inside the function `prv_write()` ? I don't really understand at this stage structs inside structs.

Ideally I'd like to print the values of all the struct members so that I can fully debug the system.

Answer (score 2):

well to print it you can simply do:

```
for (int i=0; i<dataArray->value.asbuffer.length; ++i)
    printf("%d ", dataArray->value.asBuffer.buffer[i]);
printf("\n");
```

if you need to do it in several places of your code, you can make a macro for that:

```
#define SHOW_LWM2M_DATA(DA) do { \
    for (int i=0; i< (DA)->value.asbuffer.length; ++i) \
        printf("%d", (DA)->value.asBuffer.buffer[i]); \
    printf("\n"); } while (0)
```

(the `do { } while(0)` is only there to make the macro behave like a normal function)

and use that macro in many places of your code, as it evolves:

```
pipSHOW_LWM2M_DATA(dataArray);
```

but if you want to introspect that part of the code, my advice to you is to use `gdb` (or `lldb`), and setup a watchpoint or a breakpoint use its `print` function to lookup the values, it will print the structs and arrays easily.

Comment: • Why a macro instead of a function? • The check for the correct `type` is missing. • The macro argument must be enclosed in parentheses. • There should be a space after `%d`.

Comment: → the OP said explicitely that he wants to debug/introspect some code, so as a throw away tool, a macro fills the job. But I agree a function fills the job perfectly well. → for the rest, thank you it's fixed.

Comment: You only fixed one of the three things I mentioned, so the code still invokes undefined behavior when called on a data object with the wrong type.

Comment: @zmo thanks for your input. I tried your suggestion however I'm am getting an error saying that it can't find the member `asbuffer` - here is the error, many thnaks........... `error: ‘lwm2m_data_t {aka struct _lwm2m_data_t}’ has no member named ‘asbuffer’
     for (int i=0; i<dataArray->asbuffer.length; ++i)`

Comment: @zmo I figured it out, it should be ` i<dataArray->value.asBuffer.length; ++i)` cheers